# How To Keep Leading Zeros Using PHP json_encode()

Tags: php, json

Is there an easy way to keep leading zeros in PHP using `json_encode()`?  In the example below I need the result to be `"columnA":"00123"`

```
...pdo query...
$data = $myQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//trigger_error('columnA: '.$data['columnA']); This reports it correctly: 00123
echo json_encode($data); //after this call it reports: "columnA":"123"
```

I was using the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option because I routinely returns 1s and 0s for true/false so I thought this was causing the zeros to be stripped.  So I removed that option so everything would be treated as a string but it is still removing the zeros.

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce this. It works just fine over here ~ https://eval.in/182843. In fact, it works the same in every PHP version from 5.2.0 onwards ~ http://3v4l.org/kv19o

Comment: @Phil It's data from a customer, I don't like it, I would never use IDs like this but they have values like "00123" and "123" and they need to be kept that way.  Out of my hands.

Comment: @gfrobenius This may be a silly question, but are you 100% sure that the values are being stored with the leading zeros in the database in the first place? Maybe they got lost along the way somewhere...

Comment: Are you sure you're using PHP's native `json_encode`? i.e. you're not using a json_encode() shim for an older version of PHP, right?

Comment: @MattBrowne You're probably on to something there. I wonder if OP is stuck on a RHEL box using PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Sorry fellas.  Its working now.  I didn't change anything.  I wonder if my web request was cached or something.  I tested it many times before I posted the question.  The jQuery ajax post has the cache:false though.  Strange, sorry for wasting your time.  It's WAMPSERVER 2.4 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Leading zeros will always be removed from integers and floats, so you'll need to convert the values to strings first, e.g.:

```
$data = $myQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data['columnA'] = (string)$data['columnA'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Results from PDO are automatically strings. I tried this without the cast and it works just fine as-is ~ https://eval.in/182843

Comment: @Phil Good point. I just looked it up and it seems that there's no condition under which the results returned from PDO would NOT automatically be cast to strings already. So there must be some relevant code or info the OP hasn't shown us yet...

Comment: The column is a varchar.  I query it and immediately json_encode it, just like in the example.  So when you say I need to convert it to a string I don't understand, because it's always a string.  Hmmm

Answer (score 1):

You can append a "zero width non joiner" to a number to prevent JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK from stripping the leading zeros.

```
<?php
$arr['lz'] = "0001"; 
$arr['lz'] .= "‌"; // < this contains a zero width non joiner character

print_r( json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) );
```

This will be encoded as:

```
{"lz":"0001\u200c"}
```

I prefer this method as I can use this in text output and it remains invisible (lazy)

e.g. in javascript: `console.log( arr.lz )` will appear as "0001"

I recommend stripping the character off for anything which may be required later such as an invoice number. `arr.lz.slice(0, -1)`

To generate or copy one of these characters try here: https://unicode.flopp.net/c/200C

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. I used 200B character though since the 200C character would present itself in Excel cells as a small vertical line next to my number (possibly giving the impression that a "1" was part of the number). The 200B character, however, is completely and totally invisible and still forces the value to be treated as a string in json_encode.

Comment: Also, if you want to make it explicit in your PHP code that you're appending a hidden character like this you can do something like this: $hiddenChar = "\u{200B}" and then append that variable to the string as opposed to pasting the character. This will also preserve the functionality of the code that might be opened in other software applications that remove or alter invisible characters.

Answer (score -2):

Came across the same issue while importing QR codes with trailing zeroes.
JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK causes this issue. https://3v4l.org/6Gl7M

Simply remove it and you'll be fine.